# Heroku - large static files

Tags: heroku, deployment, large-files, static-files

I'm trying to deploy my NodeJS app to Heroku with static videos up to total of 160 MB (all videos together). However, the upload speed is only 30 Kb/s and it fails at around 50%.

Is there a different way to deploy large files to your app? I know about cloud storage, however, I don't think it is necessary since they are static files.

**EDIT**

Well one way I found was to deploy them separately. That way, it's not too much to handle and thankfully all the videos can't be more than 25 MB. But it would still be good to find an alternative.

Comment: sound like google drive, for +25mb you could use Facebook instead